# How to retrieve commandline argument in java without main method

Tags: java, junit, testng

Is there any way that we can provide command line argument in JUnit or TestNG tests?

Comment: You could look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884163/pass-command-line-arguments-to-junit-test-case-being-run-programmatically

Comment: Do you want to pass parameters to the JVM (e.g. -Dsome.property=foobar) or in the way they would be passed to the `main` method (e.g. java YourApp someArgument)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.i want to pass some argument in vm argument in eclipse and retrieve from my test class.